# Celery ignores Django settings

Tags: python, django, celery

I'm using Celery for managing async tasks in Django. I set up it using the [official instruction](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html). However, when I output app.conf on my worker instance - it outputs default settings.

celery.py:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myapp.settings")

app = Celery("myapp")
app.config_from_object("django.conf:settings", namespace="CELERY")


@setup_logging.connect
def config_loggers(*args: Any, **kwags: Any) -> None:
    from logging.config import dictConfig
    from django.conf import settings

    dictConfig(settings.LOGGING)


app.autodiscover_tasks()


@celery_bound_logged_task
def debug_task(self: Any) -> None:
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.debug(f"Heartbeat: {self.request.id}")
    logger.debug("Config: %s", app.conf)  #                <------- Here I get default config, with broker_heartbeat: 120 and etc.
```

settings.py

```
# Celery
# From https://www.cloudamqp.com/docs/celery.html
CELERY_BROKER_URL = RABBITMQ_URL
CELERY_BROKER_POOL_LIMIT = 1
CELERY_BROKER_HEARTBEAT = None
CELERY_BROKER_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 30
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = None
CELERY_EVENT_QUEUE_EXPIRES = 60
CELERY_WORKER_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER = 1
CELERY_WORKER_CONCURRENCY = 1
# Never give up set up
CELERY_TASK_ACKS_LATE = True
CELERY_TASK_TIME_LIMIT = 30 * 60  # 30 minutes
CELERY_TASK_REJECT_ON_WORKER_LOST = False
CELERY_TASK_ACKS_ON_FAILURE_OR_TIMEOUT = False
```